# (Scala) Am I using Options correctly?

Tags: scala, types

I'm currently working on my functional programming - I am fairly new to it. Am i using Options correctly here? I feel pretty insecure on my skills currently. **I want my code to be as safe as possible** - Can any one point out what am I doing wrong here or is it not that bad? My code is pretty straight forward here:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
  {
    val file = "myFile.txt"
    val myGame = Game(file) //I have my game that returns an Option here

    if(myGame.isDefined) //Check if I indeed past a .txt file
    {
      val solutions = myGame.get.getAllSolutions() //This returns options as well
      if(solutions.isDefined) //Is it possible to solve the puzzle(crossword)
      {
        for(i <- solutions.get){ //print all solutions to the crossword
          i.solvedCrossword foreach println
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

-Thanks!! ^^

Comment: Why does `getAllSolutions` return an option? Is there a semantic difference between it returning `Some(Nil)` or `None`? I mean, your code treats both the same (by doing nothing), but maybe that's just a simplified version of your real code. Also am I understanding correctly that `Game()` returns `None` only in case of errors (such as the file not existing or you not having permission to read it or some IO failure)? If so, it's probably not the best solution to represent all those error cases as `None` - that loses information.

Comment: getAllSolutions return an option because if there are no solutions I would return 'None'. Game() returns 'None' as well when a file is in not correct format. Now If i return a class, right, If i know that there is an error and i want to return 'None' What else should i return? A string that explains my error? But if I have Option[myClass] - I dont want to return some string that explains my error - Do I? Thank you!

Comment: But why doesn't `getAllSolutions` just return an empty list of solutions if there are no solutions? Are there cases where you'd return `Some(Nil)` and are there situations where you'd treat `Some(Nil)` differently than `None`?

Comment: Okey, I get it. I should just return an empty list of solutions. And for the other question, if I'm getting it right - I never use Nil expressions. I think you should never do that. Thank you so much for help! ^^

Comment: Clarification: `Nil` is the empty list (not to be confused with `null`). It's the same as `List()`. Sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: Doh'! I should've known that! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you can think of `Option` as a replacement for Java's null pointer. That is, in cases where you might want to use `null` in Java, it often makes sense to use `Option` in Scala.

Your `Game()` function uses `None` to represent errors. So you're not really using it as a replacement for `null` (at least I'd consider it poor practice for an equivalent Java method to return `null` there instead of throwing an exception), but as a replacement for exceptions. That's not a good use of `Option` because it loses error information: you can no longer differentiate between the file not existing, the file being in the wrong format or other types of errors.

Instead you should use `Either`. `Either` consists of the cases `Left` and `Right` where `Right` is like `Option`'s `Some`, but `Left` differs from `None` in that it also takes an argument. Here that argument can be used to store information about the error. So you can create a case class containing the possible types of errors and use that as an argument to `Left`. Or, if you never need to handle the errors differently, but just present them to the user, you can use a string with the error message as the argument to `Left` instead of case classes.

In `getAllSolutions` you're just using `None` as a replacement for the empty list. That's unnecessary because the empty list needs no replacement. It's perfectly fine to just return an empty list when there are no solutions.

---

When it comes to interacting with the `Option`s, you're using `isDefined` + `get`, which is a bit of an anti pattern. `get` can be used as a shortcut if you know that the option you have is never `None`, but should generally be avoided. `isDefined` should generally only be used in situations where you need to know whether an option contains a value, but don't need to know the value.

In cases where you need to know both whether there is a value and what that value is, you should either use pattern matching or one of `Option`'s higher-order functions, such as `map`, `flatMap`, `getOrElse` (which is kind of a higher-order function if you squint a bit and consider by-name arguments as kind-of like functions). For cases where you want to do something with the value if there is one and do nothing otherwise, you can use `foreach` (or equivalently a `for` loop), but note that you really shouldn't do nothing in the error case here. You should tell the user about the error instead.

Comment: I don't think `Try` is a good alternative either since its left side only encodes exceptions. Only use that when calling Java API that throw exceptions. I would use `Either` instead and create a custom error hierarchy (or start simple and use `String` for the left side) instead.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for such a detailed explanation! +^^

Answer (score 4):

1. When using Option, it is recommended to use match case instead of calling 'isDefined' and 'get'
2. Instead of the java style for loop, use higher-order function:

   ```
   myGame match {
     case Some(allSolutions) =>
       val solutions = allSolutions.getAllSolutions
       solutions.foreach(_.solvedCrossword.foreach(println))
     case None =>
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this with me! ^^

Answer (score 1):

If all you need here is to print it in case all is good, you can use for-comprehension which is considered quite idiomatic Scala way

```
    for {
      myGame <- Game("mFile.txt")
      solutions <- myGame.getAllSolutions()
      solution <- solutions
      crossword <- solution.solvedCrossword
    } println(crossword)
```