# Exception in scala/java

Tags: java, scala

I'm a beginner to scala programming and jvm languages. I want to convert a string in `yyyy-MM-dd` to date format like this:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date

val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")

def strTodate(stringDate: String): Date = {
    format.parse(stringDate)
  }
```

How can I can take care of exception in case `strTodate` is called on a wrongly formatted string like strTodate("18/03/03") ? I'll like to handle the exception and also print the string

Comment: what is your `stringDate` example?? Also this is java question too, since the time api comes from java. To handle errors you can use `scala.util.Try`

Comment: I've updated the question with an example of badly formatted string I want to handle as exception

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/51136514/5986907 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/51123865/5986907

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scala has three ways to handle errors.

1. `Option`: has `None` or `Some`
2. `Try`: has `Success` or `Failure`
3. `Either`: has left or right. `Right` is always right result.

I prefer `Either` of all and here is how you can do it as `Either[String, Date]` where Left is `String`, Right is `Date`.

Example,

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
import scala.util.Try
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")

def strTodate(stringDate: String): Either[String, Date] = {
  Try {
    format.parse(stringDate)
  } match {
    case Success(s) => Right(s)
    case Failure(e: ParseException) => Left(s"bad format: $stringDate")
    case Failure(e: Throwable) => Left(s"Unknown error formatting : $stringDate")
  }
}

val date1 = strTodate("2018-09-26")
println(date1) // Right(Wed Sep 26 00:00:00 PDT 2018)

val date2 = strTodate("2018/09/26")
println(date2) // Left(bad format: 2018/09/26)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a question about `Right(s)`, is it type Date? because the idea is to use the Date if case Success else, print Failure and discard

Comment: Correct, you read `Either[String, Date]` as "my function will return Either String (on failure) or Date(on success)". `Right(value)`  wraps success value.

Comment: And in functional programming your function must return something all the time, which means you can return either actual succeded `Date` or return failed message somehow.

Comment: You also need to know about pattern match (you see match in above case, think of it as if else in imperative programming). Okay just replace `Right(s)` with `Some(s)` and then `None` instead of `Left()` and you get `Option[Date]` as a function return. That might be simpler for now.

Answer (score 0):

Handling exceptions:

```
import java.io.IOException
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date

object app  {
  val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")

  def strTodate(stringDate: String): Either[Exception, Date] = {
    try {
      Right(format.parse(stringDate))
    } catch {
      case ioException : IOException =>
        Left(ioException)
      case e: Exception =>
        Left(e)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit =
    strTodate("2018-02-02") match {
      case Right(date) => println(date)
      case Left(err) => println(err.getMessage)
    }
}
```